# LiveCycle Web Service (SOAP) NTML/Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, windows-authentication, livecycle

I'm calling a LiveCycle process via C#. Our LiveCycle server is setup to authenticate with Active Directory.

How do I enable NTML authentication for SOAP services? Right now LiveCycle returns the header

```
 WWW-Authenticate: Basic
```

I can successfully log in using Basic authentication, but I'd like to use NTML instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've found, this can't be done without heavy modification of LiveCycle and the built-in Apache server. But a workaround I found was to turn on LiveCycle Single Sign On instead. So I'm not doing "true" Kerberos delegation but this can meet our business requirements.

SSO works for both HTTP and SOAP requests.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/AdminHelp/WS92d06802c76abadb-5145d5d12905ce07e7-7f9a.2.html